# SQL Server stored procedure running in infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop

I am running a stored procedure which is running infinitely.

I have used a while loop that seems to be running without ever ending.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Id INT;
    DECLARE @iter INT = 1;
    DECLARE @iterMax INT;
    DECLARE @psubject VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @pbody NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @pSendTo NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @pProfile VARCHAR(MAX);

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdB..#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp;

    SET @pProfile = 'Test';

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM [Table_A] R
         JOIN [Table_B] T ON R.Id = T.r_Id
         WHERE R.[Date] <= (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
           AND T.[Sent_Flag] IS NULL) >= 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS RecId,
               [r_id] * 1 AS Id
        INTO #temp
        FROM [Table_A] R
        JOIN [Table_B] T ON R.Id = T.r_Id
        WHERE R.[Date] <= (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
          AND T.[Sent_Flag] IS NULL;

        BEGIN
            SET @iterMax = (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM #temp);

            WHILE (@iter <= @iterMax)
            BEGIN
                SET @psubject = 'HIIII'; /*this is in HTML example */
                SET @pbody = 'You got one email';

                IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM [Table_B]
                     WHERE R_Id = (SELECT Id FROM #temp WHERE RecId = @iter)
                       AND [Mail1_Flag] = 'Y'
                       AND [Mail2_Flag] = 'Y') = 1)
                BEGIN
                    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM [Table_A] R
                         JOIN [Table_B] T ON R.Id = T.r_Id
                         WHERE R_Id = (SELECT Id FROM #temp WHERE RecId = @iter)
                           AND R.[Date] <= (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
                           AND T.[Sent_Flag] IS NULL) = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @pSendTo = N'ABC@gmail.com';

                        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @pProfile,
                                                     @body = @pbody,
                                                     @subject = @psubject,
                                                     @recipients = @pSendTo,
                                                     @body_format = 'HTML';

                    END;

                    UPDATE [Table_B]
                    SET [Sent_Flag] = 'Y'
                    WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT Id FROM #temp WHERE RecId = @iter);
                END;
            END;

            SET @iter = @iter + 1;
        END;
    END;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempd..#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp;
END;
```

This program is checking that if date is more than 24 hours then it will send a mail correspondingly. I am able to trigger a mail. But I am getting multiple mails. Like the loop is running infinitely and getting same mail multiple times and the `sent_Flag` column is initial NULL and after a mail is sent it sholud update to 'Y' but it is also not updating to `'Y'` after mail is triggered.

Please help to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: The fact that you are using a `WHILE` loop in the first place infers a design flaw. What are you trying to achieve with the SP? Also, I note that in your `WHILE (@iter <= @iterMax)` section you never change the value of `@iter ` or `@iterMax`, so that `WHILE` will never be exitted. (You can see this quite easily now too, as I formatted and aligned your code for you.)

Comment: Why not do the processing based on the value of `Sent_Flag`?

Comment: ^ Instead of `WHILE (@iter <= @iterMax)` use `WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp WHERE Sent_Flag IS NULL)`

Comment: Honestly, this type of one-by-one looping is what cursors are made for. Your coding is much simpler to understand (but frowned upon by many) if you use a cursor.

Comment: But to be clear, a cursor is no better or worse than a while loop in terms of performance (it's a common misconception that while loops are "better").

Comment: SET @ iter = @ iter + 1; in wrong place, should be one inner level END

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the counter inside the loop:

```
                UPDATE [Table_B]
                SET [Sent_Flag] = 'Y'
                WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT Id FROM #temp WHERE RecId = @iter);
            END;   --this is the END of the first IF BEGIN
        END;  --this is the END of the WHILE BEGIN

        SET @iter = @iter + 1;   --and here you update the counter, which will never be reached
```

If you don't increment the counter inside the loop, the loop will run infinitely, since the loop condition will always be true.